# get the right php command to run module

Tags: magento2

i just installed the XAMPP in my localhost. Can i know how do i able to run the following command in my localhost?

```
$ php bin/magento module:enable xxx...
```

My xampp command prompt is always showing '#', how do i convert that to '$'? It always say the PHP is not recognized as the internal or external command. I have tried navigate to xampp/php/php.exe but it does not trigger the php command either.

Comment: Generally speaking, you run that command from where you install your root magento directory.  Have you done this?

Comment: Yes, i have tried to run that command in my root folder... but it said bin is not a recognized command. That is why i wonder how am i able to start the command with $ php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the XAMPP control panel you click the 'Shell' button. In the console prompt, type `cd htdocs/{magento-directory}` using the name of your magento directory. Now you can enter the command :

`php bin/magento module:enable {module-name}`

Answer (score 3):

Ok so this a 2 step check you need to do:

Firstly check if **PHP** is present in the environment path of your system. You can do that by checking if `php` gets resolved by the command prompt.

```
where php
```

If you get a response like:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

Its more than likely that **PHP** is not accessible by the command prompt.

So we need to add an entry to the global `PATH` variable. Right click on `My Computer` -> `Advanced system settings` -> `Environment Variables..`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is `system variables` find the variable `path`, double click on it

[image]

Now on the `variable value` field add a `;` at the end of the line and add the folder where your PHP lies.

```
Example -> C:\xampp\php
```

[image]

Now press `OK`.

Also make sure you restart start your command prompt window.

Now to check if the new value added is getting reflected at you command prompt

```
echo %PATH%
```

This should output something like:
    ...C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\xampp\php

make sure the newly added path if the PHP directory is present in the output. Also the `where` command should now out the path of the PHP directory added.

```
where php
C:\xampp\php
```

Second make sure that the when you are executing the command

```
php bin/magento
```

You are executing this from the root of the application. For example if your project is present in `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2` make sure you navigate into the folder from you command prompt, before you execute the `bin/magento` command.

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2
```

Hope this helps.